Nash Bargaining: Understanding why equal split isn't pure strategy Nash equilibrium
There are 2 players who have to decide how to split one dollar. The bargaining process works as follows. Players simultaneously announce the share they would like to receive $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$, with $0 \leq s_{1}, s_{2} \leq 1$. If $s_{1}+s_{2} \leq 1$, then the players receive the shares they named and if $s_{1}+s_{2}>1$, then both players fail to achieve an agreement and receive zero. This game is known as 'Nash Bargaining'. Which of the following strategy profiles is a pure strategy Nash equilibrium?
a) $(0.3, 0.7)$;
b) $(0.5, 0.5)$;
c) $(1.0, 1.0)$;
d) All of the above

I got above question in Cousera course: Game thoery , my initial answer is B, I got the answer because :
pair can be considered stable as neither player has an incentive to deviate from his choice
I think split in half make the game stable, but it tell me I'm wrong, whats wrong with me?

Given the availability of answer (d), even if (b) were a Nash equilibrium you would still also need to consider (a) and (c).

You can think about if the player has the incentive to change by considering his payoff when his action changes. For example, you can verify $(0.5,0.5)$ is a pure NE by seeing that $$u_1(s,0.5)=\begin{cases}s\quad\text{if $s\le0.5$}\\0\quad\text{if $s>0.5$}\end{cases}\quad\forall s>0$$
where $u_i$ is the payoff of player $i$ and from this you can see $s=0.5$ is a best-response to to player $1$. By symmetry, it is also for player $2$. Thus $(0.5,0.5)$ is a pure NE.
Now try to show that both (a) and (c) are also NE by similar arguments.
